# How to run binary from a lambda properly?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to make sox audio binary run from the lambda, I followed this guide: http://marcelog.github.io/articles/static_sox_transcoding_lambda_mp3.html
So I created sox binary using docker with last Amazon Linux version and deployed lambda as zip package with structure:

```
sox
index.js
```

Lambda code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    initializeContext();

    try {
        const object = await getFile("test.mp3");

        const fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/test.mp3", object.Body);

        let result = child_process.execFileSync('sox', ['/tmp/test.mp3', '/tmp/testOutput.mp3', ... <filter params here>], {
            encoding: 'ascii'
            // shell: true
        });

        const file = fs.readFileSync("/tmp/testOutput.mp3");

        await putFile("testOutput.mp3", file);
    }
    catch(err) {
        try {
            await log("error", err); 
        }
        catch(err) {}
    }
};
let getFile = async function(fileName) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName
    };
    return await s3.getObject(params).promise();
};

let putFile = async function(fileName, body) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: body
    };
    await s3.putObject(params).promise();
};
```

So, I need to get file from S3, process it and return result. S3 loading is tested to work. However, I get "EACCES" error on trying to start "sox" process.
What could I miss? Can it originate from the fact that I used the last Amazon Linux image but Lambda use more old version?

Comment: Could it be ```sox```is trying to write in a different path that ```/tmp``` ?

Comment: @OscarNevarez I've checked your idea by running "child_process.execFileSync('sox', ['-h'],{...}). Still get the error.

Comment: Are you sure that the `sox` executable is in the running directory, and not in some subdirectory?

Comment: @Kalev - it's in the same directory as index.js of lambda

Comment: If "process.env["PATH"] = process.env["PATH"] + ":" + process.env["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"];" removed, get ENOENT error

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Then my next question is what are the permissions on the file?

Comment: @Kalev I set 777 on Amazon Linux where file was created but does it make any sense? Frankly speaking, as windows user I still don't get that linux permission. As I thought, they are stored in the system, not file, so if I put 777 file into .zip, download to AWS Lambda, it should have the permission that Lambda running system (and not the one where file was created) decided to set for it during copying on start, doesn't it? And I don't have any idea how to change those permissions.

Comment: One step at a time. It makes sense, but I would double check in the actual execution environment. Add the line `child_process.execSync('ls -l')` to the lambda function, and look at the result. The output should include a line with the `sox` executable you compiled, and something like `-rwxrwxrwx`. If the `sox` executable is not there, or if the permissions don't start with `-rwx`, then that's your problem.

Comment: @Kalev I've found the issue was related to runtime. When I set to Node 6.10 and updated code accordingly it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that to ensure file permissions I have to create zip package inside Amazon Linux docker image. So you need to

```
npm i lambda-audio
```

there, then zip node_modules along with your index.js.
My lambda package zip root folder is:

```
node_modules // npm i lambda-audio result
index.js
```

Working solution for Node 8.10 Runtime with memory consumption optimizations:

```
process.env["PATH"] = process.env["PATH"] + ":" + process.env["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"];

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const lambdaAudio = require("lambda-audio");

let bucket;

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        bucket = event.bucket;
        const { inputFileName, outputFileName } = event;

        const fs = require("fs");
        const inputStream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/input.mp3");

        await getFileToStream(inputFileName, inputStream);

        await lambdaAudio.sox("/tmp/input.mp3 /tmp/output.mp3 <YOUR FILTERS HERE>);

        fs.unlinkSync("/tmp/input.mp3"); // removing unused input file

        const outputStream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/output.mp3");
        await uploadFileFromStream(outputFileName, outputStream);
    }
    catch(err) {
        // Logging
    }
};

let getFileToStream = async function(fileName, writeStream) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName
    };
    const readStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();

    const end = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writeStream.on('close', () => resolve());
        writeStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
        readStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    });

    readStream.pipe(writeStream);

    return end;
};

let uploadFileFromStream = async function(fileName, readStream) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: readStream
    };
    return await s3.upload(params).promise();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same for processing audio files. The npm package came handy.

https://github.com/stojanovic/lambda-audio

If your command is,

> sox input.mp3 -c 1 output.wav

your node code will be like the following,

```
const lambdaAudio = require('lambda-audio')
lambdaAudio.sox('./input.mp3 -c 1 /tmp/output.wav')
  .then(response => {
    // Do something when the file was converted
  })
  .catch(errorResponse => {
    console.log('Error from the sox command:', errorResponse)
  })
```

and leave all the complex issues to the npm package.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I started from lambda-audio. It throwed EACESS, so I've decided that it is outdated (at least sox/lame bins in it). Then I compliled sox on new Amazon Linux version. Put sox bin into the package bin folder. Got the error again. Tried to call sox manually. Got the problem again and asked question here.

Comment: I had to move the sox to /tmp folder and chmod 755 on  /tmp/sox folder and run it from there. Eventhough if your zip file contains permissions, lambda deployment reset permissions for those and those are just read-only.

Comment: Please clarify - your archive structure now is like in root index.js and tmp folder with sox in it, right? How then lamba-audio finds sox if it's location was changed?

Comment: I do see there are two environment settings. SOX_PATH=/tmp/sox and NODE_ENV=test. That is used on this lambda. Code reference: https://github.com/stojanovic/lambda-audio/blob/master/lib/lambda-audio.js

Comment: I've found the issue was related to runtime. When I set to Node 6.10 and updated code accordingly it worked. Thank you for your help.